# unable to do ajax servlet call from JSP form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am creating a simple 2 page page-loader in ajax. in the index.jsp I have a `<form>` with text field and a submit button.
When I hit the `submit` button, it would go to the servlet that does nothing but sleeps for 3 seconds and then redirects to second.jsp
In those 3 seconds sleep I want to show a page loader.
I am trying to call the ajax function from the `onclick` but nothing is working.
Below is the code:
index.jsp:

```
<html>
<head><title>first</title>
<link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.10.2.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/toSecond',
        data: {
            //name: $('#name').val()
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            document.getElementById('loader').show();
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert('completed');           
        },
        error:function(){
            // failed request; give feedback to user
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit" onclick="callAjax();"/>
</form>

<div class="modal" id="loader"></div> <!--a page-loader GIF defined in the css -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}

/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
   the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
   modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

Servlet:

```
public class TempServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String name = (String)req.getParameter("name");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher  = req.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);

    }

}
```

second.jsp:

```
<html>
<head><title>first</title>
</head>
<body>
second page
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>TEMP</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>toSecond</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>TempServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>toSecond</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/toSecond</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

where am i going wrong ? Am I not making a proper Ajax call from the html-form?

Comment: `<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit" onclick="callAjax();"/>` change this to `<input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="submit" onclick="callAjax();"/>` and try because `type="submit"` would submit the whole page.

Comment: Its giving me the exception "Uncaught ReferenceError: callAjax is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick"  in the Chrome developer tool console

Comment: Try that with jQuery click function `$('#submitBtn').on('click', function () { /*Call your ajax*/ })`.

Comment: I changed the script to <script type="text/javascript">
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function () { 
 /*Call your ajax*/ 
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/toSecond',
  data: {
   //name: $('#name').val()
  },
  beforeSend:function(){
   document.getElementById('loader').show();
  },
  success:function(data){
   alert('completed');           
  },
  error:function(){
   // failed request; give feedback to user
  }
 });

});
</script> and removed the onclick="callAjax();" from input-tag. But page is not redirecting to the servlet...it is staying on index.jsp

Comment: Just debug and see whether the ajax request goes to controller or not ?

Comment: I don’t have any ajax controller code written in my app.